# How can I create Android module library inside Android module library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, project-structure

I try to create module which is controller for XXX sdk module. So I create new module library (controller) and want to add sub module XXX sdk module. Can you give some advises how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 library modules. Something like:

```
root
|--libA
|----build.gradle
|--libB
|----build.gradle
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':libA' , ':libB'
```

In `libA/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

//
```

In `libB/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile project(':libA')
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriele. I used this structure from beginning and it is the best solution

Comment: @Alex if the answer solves your question, mark the answer. it can help other users.